# How to handle file upload in symfony?

Tags: symfony

im trying to upload diffrent types of files in symfony

```
$uploadedFile = $request->files->get('image');
```

Works good for handling with images, However i cannot use it with diffrent files than

```
$uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
dd($uploadedFile);
```

Whatever i send using this, dd method shows me null.
How can I upload files for example pdfs, docx etc. (diffrent than images)
I use vue on the frontend.

Comment: Because base on your $uploadedFile variable your only targeting the file type of "image". You can check the official docs for uploading of file, check it here https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use createForm.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

```
 $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var UploadedFile $brochureFile */
            $brochureFile = $form->get('brochure')->getData();

            // this condition is needed because the 'brochure' field is not required
            // so the PDF file must be processed only when a file is uploaded
            if ($brochureFile) {
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($brochureFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
                $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$brochureFile->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
                try {
                    $brochureFile->move(
                        $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                        $newFilename
                    );
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                    // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
                }

                // updates the 'brochureFilename' property to store the PDF file name
                // instead of its contents
                $product->setBrochureFilename($newFilename);
            }
```